# Healpy Mollview half-sky

Tags: matplotlib, healpy

This question has two parts:

Part 1: the main issue I'm having is in trying to do a half-sky plot using healpy mollview. The current workaround I'm using is this:

```
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w, h = 6, 4
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(w,h))

map = np.arange(hp.nside2npix(64))
hp.mollview(map, fig=1)
hp.graticule(verbose=False)

for ax in fig.get_axes():
    if type(ax) is hp.projaxes.HpxMollweideAxes:
        ax.set_ylim(-1, 0.005)
fig.set_size_inches(w, h/2.8, forward=True)

plt.show()
```

This feels a little clumsy, so I'm looking for a better way to approach the problem.

Part 2: the second issue is with the title. Is there any way to make the map without a title altogether?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

here is a piece of code which plots the upper half of the map without a title and without the color map.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import healpy as hp
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

NSIDE=128
m=np.arange(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE))

hp.mollview(m, title="", cbar=False)
pl.xlim([0,1])

pl.show()
```

hope it helps.